# host a website built using Laravel Framework version 5.6

Tags: php, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting, laravel-5.6

I want to host a website built using Laravel Framework version 5.6 that requires at least PHP version 7.1. Unfortunately, the only supported PHP versions that we've found in the CPanel are 7.0 downwards.

How do I add support for PHP v 7.1 onwards in cPanel? or this is povider-dependent, i.e. the hoster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no actual question here, but CPanel supports higher versions of PHP. I am currently running several Laravel websites on version 7.1. I can't answer more in depth as to your situation without more information. Here is the link to the CPanel instructions on how to add new PHP versions to your account. [CPanel Documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/How+to+Locate+and+Install+a+PHP+Version+or+Extension)

Comment: The problem here is with the provider, where I select php version in the CPanel provided by our provider, I can only select v 7.0 downwards. No v 7.1 is found. So my question, Is there anyway I can add support for 7.1 or this is dependent on the provider?

Comment: It's possible that your provider has restricted it, but I think it's more likely that you don't have that package installed. MultiPHP will only show you the installed versions. You have to use EasyApache4 to install the PHP 7.1 module.

Comment: I didn't find so far any EasyApache4 in my cPanel. How can I install it?

Comment: Contact your hosting provide and request that they install it on your account.